# JFrame window doesn't appear

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

My code below is creating a JFrame window with basic components, I was running to test but the window doesn't show up. I'm working on Eclipse.

```
package B3;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrameB3 extends JFrame {
    
    JLabel shape, shapeLabel, fullname, fullNameLabel, gender, genderLabel, color, colorLabel, school, schoolLabel, ageRange, ageRangeLabel; 
    
    public void MainFrameB3() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4,10,3));
        panel1.add(shape = new JLabel("Loai hinh"));
        panel1.add(fullname = new JLabel("Ho va Ten"));
        panel1.add(gender = new JLabel("Gioi tinh"));
        panel1.add(shapeLabel = new JLabel("Hinh tron"));
        panel1.add(fullNameLabel = new JLabel(""));
        panel1.add(genderLabel = new JLabel("Nam"));
        panel1.add(color = new JLabel("Mau sac"));
        panel1.add(school = new JLabel("Hoc truong"));
        panel1.add(ageRange = new JLabel("Trong do tuoi"));
        panel1.add(colorLabel = new JLabel("Mau xanh"));
        panel1.add(schoolLabel = new JLabel(""));
        panel1.add(ageRangeLabel = new JLabel("6 - 12"));
        mainPanel.add(panel1);
        
        
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        setTitle("Khao sat thong tin");
        setSize(300,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MainFrameB3();
    }
}
```

I tried to restart the Eclipse as well as check Task Manager but nothing worked, there is no JFrame task showing in Task Manager.

Comment: `public void MainFrameB3() {` is a method, not a constructor, remove `void` or call `new MainFrameB3().MainFrameB3();`, but I think you'll agree, removing `void` will produce cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `void` from the `MainFrameB3()`, because with `void` it will be a method and without it will be a constructor.
Check the [How to Make Frames(Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) documentation for more information

Comment: Please add a link to the section you are mentioning